# Parallelism in a sentence regarding transitive verbs, gerunds, and objects

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, parallelism, intransitive-verbs, transitive-verbs

I'm trying to write this sentence, but something doesn't seem right:

Walloopp.com is the place to discover, collaborate, and create what's next.

The first two are just options for actions on the website (you can discover, and you can collaborate,) and the third is the option to create what's next.

However, it seems like creating what's next is the object here, and collaborate would thus require "on" for it to make sense since you can't "collaborate what's next".

The question is (I think) can you have an intransitive verb, set off by another infinitive, followed by a transitive verb with an object without the previous verbs also having to modify it?

_

p.s. this could be fixed with recasting it e.g., "The place to discover and create what's next—together." but in this particular case (my job) that would require a lot of time (coding).

Merci d'Avance!

Comment: I agree with your analysis that the sentence should read, "Walloopp.com is the place to discover, collaborate on, and create what's next." That sounds fine to my ear. Do you find it objectionable?

Comment: I do find it objectionable – to the ear – because ON makes the jingle quality of the sentence disappear

Comment: @Mark Hubbard Yes, but the prep "on" requires a complement, and there isn't one anywhere to be seen. I can't see anything wrong with the OP's example, as written.

Comment: @BillJ "*Collaborate on* what's next."

Comment: @ Mark Hubbard I know what you mean, but "create" doesn't take the prep "on", so it doesn't seem to work: *_collaborate and create on what's next_. I still think the OP's original sentence is fine where "collaborate" has no complement at all.

Comment: @Lambie 'Collaborate' without a PP is certainly grammatical, but sounds vacuous here without one.

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete my post. I fail to see why collaborate requires on. It doesn't. It's the lack of object with discover that bothers my "ear": Walloopp.com is the place to discover what's new, collaborate on what's now, and create what's next. –

Answer (score 1):

The United States Declaration of Independence
refers to "Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness". 
Converting this to verbs, we get "live, be free, and pursue happiness". 
Or one could say
"restaurant X is a good place to eat, drink, and watch sports on television." 
So it seems that you *can* have intransitive verbs,
followed by a transitive verb with an object,
without the previous verbs also having to refer to it.

On the other hand, if the sentence means
"... discover what's next, collaborate on what's next, and create what's next,"
then that's a somewhat different kettle of fish. 
But I would question whether you can "discover" and "create" in parallel —
you discover things that already exist,
and you create (or invent) things that don't.